# How to create array of all channels under a group of category IDs?

Tags: discord.js

I've done what I believe produces an array of IDs of categories, and this is my code to try and use their IDs to return the keys of their children channels.

```
    var filtered_category_ids = [""];
    var filtered_category_ids = filtered_category_ids.reduce((acc, id) => 
    acc.push(filtered_category_names.findKey((c) => c.name === name)));
    var filtered_channel_ids = [];
    const children = this.children;
    filtered_category_ids.forEach(element => filtered_channel_ids.push((children.keyArray())));
    console.log(filtered_channel_ids);
```

However, on running it, I get the TypeError "filtered_category_ids.forEach is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `Array.prototype.reduce` is very important. It's the value that `acc` will take on at the beginning. If there is no second argument, it will take on the value of the first element in the array.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)) // acc starts as `1`
console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 10)) // but what if we wanted it to start at `10`
```

This parameter is basically required when working with arrays, objects, etc.

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, curr) => acc.push(curr))) // right now, `acc` is `1` (not an array; does not have the .push() method)
```

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, curr) => acc.push(curr), [])); // start with an empty array
```

However, there is a second problem (as you can see from the above snippet). `Array.prototype.push()` actually returns the array's *length*, not the array itself.

```js
console.log(
  [1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push(curr); // push element to array
    return acc; // but return the arr itself
  }, [])
);

// second (simplified) method
console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []))
```

You can also use `Array.from()`, which would be simpler in this situation.

```js
console.log(Array.from([1, 2, 3], (num) => num);
```

---

There are a few other wonky things in your code, so here's what I suggest you do:

```js
var filtered_category_names = ['']; // I think you might've meant `category_names` instead of `ids`

// you're trying to get IDs from names, so I'm not sure why you're reducing the ID array (before it's established)
// and using id as a parameter name when you use `name` in the actual function
var filtered_category_ids = Array.from(filtered_category_names, (name) => 
 client.channels.cache.findKey((c) => c.name === name)
);

var filtered_channel_ids = [];
filtered_category_ids.forEach((id) =>
 // filtered_channel_ids.push(children.keyArray()) // you're adding the same value to the array multiple times?

 // get the category's children and add their IDs to the array
 filtered.channel.ids.push(client.channels.cache.get(id).children.keyArray())
);
console.log(filtered_channel_ids);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me again!